# How can I automatically add data to the database on a weekly basis?

Tags: python, django

I want to add a 'Weekstaat' to the database automatically every end of the week.

model:

```
class Weekstaat(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False, blank=False)
    #status = models.ForeignKey(Status, null=False, blank=False, default=1,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    jaar = models.ForeignKey(Jaar, default=datetime.now().year, null=False, blank=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    week = models.ForeignKey(Week, default=date.today().isocalendar()[1], null=False, blank=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    werknemer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='weekstaat_werknemer', null=False, blank=False, default=1,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    maandag = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    dinsdag = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    woensdag = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    donderdag = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    vrijdag = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    zaterdag = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    zondag = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.jaar) + ' week ' + str(self.week) + str(self.werknemer)
```

view:

```
class weekstaat(generic.ListView):
    model = Weekstaat
    context_object_name = 'Weekstaten'
    template_name = 'weekstaat/index.html'
```

Comment: you can create a `cron` job. It will automatically update according to the specified time.

Answer (score 0):

you can write CRON JOBS for this here is some CRON packages for Django
**[Django-CRON](https://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)**

https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/cron/